# write to database tomcat

Tags: android, tomcat, tomcat7

i using java method trying to implement write servlet into database by creating table tm7(name varchar(20)); but the codes somehow doesnt insert into database by tomcat. any experts can save this ?? thanks!! (sorry kinda new to this)

```
my tomcat writeservlet file

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            req.getInputStream()));
    String names;

    while ((names = reader.readLine()) != null) // read from mobile device
    {
        Statement stmt;
        String sgd = names;
        String name = sgd.toString();

        try {
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tm7 VALUES ('" + name
                    + "') ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        System.out.println(name);
    }

    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.println(" server received");
}
```

}

my main android java

```
 private class NetworkTask2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    String line="";
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String address=params[0];
        try{
        URL url = new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
        out.write(one.getText().toString());//get converted value
        //out.write(two.getText().toString());//get converted value
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        line=br.readLine();// read back response from server
        }
    catch(IOException e){Log.e("error", "mm", e); }

        return line;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        one.setText(result);
        //two.setText(result);
   }
}
```

Comment: hmmm so you did not write any line on the client side and expect to get one on the server side?

Comment: i using sharedpreference and using string name in the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest to detect the problem is at server or client side. Very easy both case:

Start with debugger in Android and see if is called.
Start with debugger the Server side app and check if is in `doPost` method what is called, where it goes the flow.

Fix error and is done.

```
      try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tm7 VALUES ('" + name
                + "') ");

     // add this lines:
     con.flush(); 
     con.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {           
        e.printStacktace() // at least
    }
```

Comment: for some reason i cant add con.flush() instead of ((PrintWriter) con).flush();  but theres a error opening file : no such file or directory (2) in the logcat

Comment: @dawfawf At server side somewhere is opened the connection to database. I am not sure why not in doPost() method, -probably because you are using a copy-paste coding and now wondering why isn't working - but there should be a settings with autoflush the connection or not. Make sure the Java will send the statement to mysql or whatever database ( do a log )

Comment: yup i done a log  Intent log = new Intent(LogActivity.this,MainForm.class);
   log.putExtra("pass1",two.getText().toString());
   log.putExtra("pass2",one.getText().toString());

Comment: ofc not there need to put the logs... Sorry if my answer doesn't help you and not worth an upvote, I can't teach you programming in 1h anyway. Just start with Debugg method both the server both the android. Put breakpoint and use step into and step over to see what is moving and where.